# Best practices to convert Firebase database having dynamic values to kotlin data classes

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, pojo, data-class

My firebase realtime database has dynamic values for nodes(under services such as Beard - Trim, Facial, Hair coloring etc.).

What would be the best practices to convert it to Kotlin data class(Java POJO)?

[image]

```
data class User constructor(
    var services: List<Services>
)

data class Services constructor(
    var description: String = "",
    var duration: String = "",
    var name: String = "",
    var picture: String = "",
    var picture_url: String = "",
    var price: String = "",
    var thumbnail: String = "",
    var thumbnail_url: String = ""
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, solved the issue with Map (instead of List) as the data receives from the Firebase as Map.

```
var services: Map<String, Services>
```

Folks, thank you all for support.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have each field of the data class a nullable `var`, your class will work perfectly fine. It doesn't matter what is the key of your node. It could be a custom string as it is in your case or even a random id that is generated by the [push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#push()) method.

But remember, using those custom names for your keys may work for small data sets but in case of larger applications it might not scale. So it's better to use those random keys provided by the `push()` method.

Comment: Given all the properties have default values, it's not required that they be nullable (I imagine they'd only be marked nullable if null is the desired default).

Comment: Yes, since you have initialized all of them in the costructor it will work just fine.

Comment: Alex, thanks for the support. Certainly, appreciates the effort. Lemme get back on this.

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.